# Data locking prevents query from running - MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, rowlocking, table-locking

We need to run a script every 24h that calculates sums & avarages of data from 1 big log table and updates the data in the Main_Table (Innodb) that has many select/update queries all the time (about 1 per second)

I ran a test query on a local DB which took about 10 minutes:

```
Update Main_Table Set Steps = (Select count(*) From Log_Activity Where Log_Activity.MainID = Main_Table.ID)
```

And because this updates all the rows in the Main_Table everything get stuck in the live project because of table loacking I guess - I had to kill the process of the query in order for this to start working properly again - no data was updated.

I did some digging and I'm considering the following 3 options:

1. Update all data in a temp table and then merge into the Main_Table somehow.
2. Run the script in php loops instead of 1 MySql query (will take much
   more time, but update 1 row at a time).
3. I'm not sure if this has to do with our problem but I read
   something about "START TRANSACTION... etc'" and I think this might
   be related... is it?

Hope someone can shed some light on this and help us.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an index on `Log_Activity.MainID`, if one does not already exist:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Log_Activity ADD INDEX (MainID);
   ```
2. Create an index on `Main_Table.ID`, if one does not already exist:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Main_Table ADD INDEX (ID);
   ```
3. Rewrite your query to use a join, rather than a correlated subquery:

   ```
   UPDATE Main_Table JOIN (
     SELECT   MainID ID, COUNT(*) c
     FROM     Log_Activity
     GROUP BY MainID
   ) t USING (ID)
   SET Main_Table.Steps = t.c;
   ```

Comment: Thanks eggyal! However I prefer not to create an index for Log_Activity.MainID because this table gets many inserts per minute (sometimes per second) and this is expected to grow..) any other ideas?